# How to Spoof ip in java

Tags: java, ip, spoofing

How to change tcp information in layer 3 in java ?(ip spoofing) how to  change layer 2 information ? is there any good library for it in java ? it need raw socket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JpCap may be what you want http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/

Comment: Or jNetPcap (http://jnetpcap.com/) will also do it. I find http://jnetpcap.com/ easier to use.

Comment: None of these links work. can anyone update these links?

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately to need access to the TCP/IP packet structures you need to work at very low level (you need the kernel headers in Linux for instance) so yes, you will definitely 100% need to do this outside java in a native library and call the code in your Java app.